# Cant find "StyleApplication" toolbar in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

As Joe Stagnner in his asp.net tutorial has used `Style Application` and `target rule`  for creatng css code. I can't find any toolbar named `StyleApplication`.

Can anyone pls help me to locate this toolbar which gives me both option of style application and target rule? Tried experimenting with toolbars still not able to find.

Answer (score 1):

It's merged with `Formatting` toolbar. There is `Target rule` drop down, `Reuse existing style` and `Show overlay` buttons in `Formatting` toolbar.

Comment: It is enabled in design mode, why so...I don't know :)